# BMI python 3 numpy-how do i use numpy to get an 'obese' print result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm a beginner in python.Can you help me because for some reason the print isn't working here?

```
import numpy

height=float(input('height (m):'))
weight=float(input('weight (kg):'))
BMI=round(weight/(height*height),1)
if BMI in numpy.arange(18.5,24.9):
    print ('Normal weight')
elif BMI in numpy.arange(25,29.9):
    print ('Overweight')
elif BMI in numpy.arange(30,41):
    print ('Obese')
elif BMI > 40:
    print ('Morbidly obese')
elif BMI < 18.5:
    print ('underweight')

print ('BMI:',round(BMI,1))
```

Comment: Hello, please show us the error or stacktrace. Provide also requested behaviour of your program? Have you debugged it?

Answer (score 1):

`for BMI in numpy.arange(18.5,24.9)` defines a loop in Python. Here BMI will take integer values 19, 20, 21 ... 24 as defined by `np.arange`. This makes you print 'Normal weight' seven times.

You probably want this:

```
if 18.5 < BMI < 24.9:
    print ('Normal weight')
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way  to  use numpy in the BMI calculator

Comment: You can use `np.round(weight/(height*height),1)`? Otherwise, this answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

The function `numpy.arange(a, b)` will produce integers between a and b (not including b). This is not what you want, because the variable BMI could take on non-integer values. So it is better to use inequality tests, such as:

```
if 30 < BMI < 41:
    print("Obese")
```

If you keep `numpy.arange(a, b)` then it is likely that you will never enter some of the if statements. Consider BMI = 34.6. In this case, it should be classified as "Obese". However, since BMI does not equal an integer value between 30 and 41, that if statement will be skipped.

Comment: so are you saying it'll work if i just add 0.1 step?

Comment: If you expect your BMI value to only be accurate to the tenths decimal place, then yes. If however, you get a BMI value of 34.657, then no.